# Script on startup unable to use USB audio

Tags: audio, usb-audio

I'm working on a very simple raspberry pi project where a Python script runs in the background and plays an `mp3` on keyboard input. Everything works fine when I launch the script manually while SSH'd into the device. But I want the script to always be running. I originally added it to `rc.local`, then I switched it to run via crontab with `@reboot`. In both cases, the script is definitely running. I get logs every time a key is successfully recognized, so the script is running and executing the sound. However, no audio comes out. I've tried Python's `playsound` module and running an `mpg321` subprocess. Both output sound when run manually but neither work on startup.

This only happens when I automatically run the script on startup with USB speakers. If I run it manually when logged in, the speakers work. If I run it on startup with speakers plugged into the 3.5mm port, it also works. It's just when running on startup with USB speakers that it doesn't work.

I print `lsusb` and `aplay -l` output when the script runs. The USB speakers ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075M7FHM1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075M7FHM1)) definitely exist when the script runs.

`lsusb` output (Jieli is definitely the speakers):

```
2023-09-17 19:37:45.976133: Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 4c4a:4155 Jieli Technology UACDemoV1.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`aplay -l` output (once card 1: UACDemoV10 is the speakers):

```
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: UACDemoV10 [UACDemoV1.0], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: vc4hdmi [vc4-hdmi], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I'm using absolute paths to everything, the script definitely runs, and the audio files can be found. It's just no audio actually comes out. The USB speakers are recognized by the time the script runs. Is there a better way to launch the script automatically on boot? Do `rc.local` or `cron` environments lack permissions or access to the USB devices? A note on one of my other questions said "rc.local is run by root so has no access to user I/O", but I thought the user's crontab wouldn't have that issue.